# What is the Fourier transform? (Symmetric invertible matrix)

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-transform

What is the Fourier transform of
$$
e^{ia\langle Ax,x \rangle/2}
$$
where $a>0$ and $A$ is a symmetric invertible matrix such that $\Im(A) \geq 0$ (i.e. $\Im\langle Ax, x\rangle \geq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$). I would be satisfied with a method for finding the Fourier transform in the case where $A$ is real. The answer is supposed to be
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\det(aA/2\pi i)}}e^{-i\langle Ax, x\rangle/2a}
$$
In the above, I am not sure what the author means by the square root since the argument might not be in $\mathbb{R}_{\geq 0}$. In that case, there will be two posible values and I am not sure how to pick the right one.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What do you mean by $\Im(A)$?

Comment: I couldn't find in the book where the notation was explained but the author did write: $\Re(A) \geq 0$ if $\langle \Re A x, x \rangle \geq 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ (with the $\Re$ symbol written inside the inner product). I was hoping it was standard notation that I wasn't aware of. I suppose it means that all $\Im\langle Ax, x \rangle \geq 0$ for all $x\in \mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and therefore decided to answer my own question. First, note that by writing $iA = -B$ where $B = -iA$ it suffices to show that
$$
\mathcal{F}\left(e^{-a\langle Bx, x\rangle/2}\right)(\xi)
= \left(\frac{2\pi}{a}\right)^{n/2}\frac{1}{\sqrt{\det(B)}}e^{\frac{-1}{2a}\langle B^{-1}\xi, \xi\rangle}
$$
This can be done by first considering the case where $B$ is positive definite. Then we use the result on $B+\epsilon I$ and take the limit as  $\epsilon \to 0$.